# How to implement FOSUserBundle register form in other pages

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

So, I'm using the FOSUserBundle and I want to implement the register form in a pop-up module that will appear when the user clicks on a button so that he can register.

I already have a separate register page, and I managed to extend the register form like this ...

```
<form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST">

                {{ form_widget(form) }}

                <button type="Submit">{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}</button>

 </form>
```

But that only works because I have the same folder structure the FOSUserBundle has (views/registration/register.html.twig), and that's the only way I know to extend the register form or any form from the FOSUserBundle, but now I want to add the form this module, and when I do this ...

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Register</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST">

                            {{ form_widget(form) }}

                            <button type="Submit">{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}</button>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- register -->
```

It doesn't work, because it's in a different location all together.

I want to use the register form globally, so that I can call that pop-up module in any page I want.
No, how can I do that?

Comment: Where is the code of your action in the controller?

Comment: Specify what u r trying to do. U always can extend FOSUserBundle if u r using symfony. Also FOSUserBundle verison could be useful.

Comment: I want to use the register form globally, so that I can call that pop-up module in any page I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get it right all u need to do is to create some popup window with reg form on yor site.

I would do that trick this way: in your layout template u create some block, like

```
{% block modal_registration %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        {{ render(controller('UrBundle:Registration:regForm')) }}
    </div><!-- register -->
{% endblock %}
```

That can be easily replaced with some twig extension.

Then, create ur controller for rendering that block, it should look similar to this:

```
class RegistrationController extends ContainerAware
{
    public function regFormAction()
    {      

        /** @var  \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface $formFactory*/
        $formFactory = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');        

        $form = $formFactory->createForm();

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('UrBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
 }
```

As u can see form factory is just a service, so u can access it via your container.

And template for this block can look like yours:

```
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Register</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST">

                        {{ form_widget(form) }}

                        <button type="Submit">{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}</button>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Example is really simplified, u should do some work, if u'll face further problems.